# If an $R$-module $M \cong M \oplus M$ then if $S=\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)$ we have $S \cong S \oplus S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, modules

If an $R$-module $M \cong M \oplus M$ then if $S=\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)$ we have $S \cong S \oplus S$

$proof:$ So I need help with the details, but in general I was hoping something like this would work,

$\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(M \oplus M,M \oplus M) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)$

Is this right? The first $\cong$ would mean that $\operatorname{Hom}_R$ is invariant under isomorphism classes, or at least in the case of endomorphisms as we have here, which makes perfect sense to me.

I could see the second $\cong$ holding as well, but wouldn't mind somebody helping me spell out the details. Thanks!

Comment: No, you are missing 2 homs! generally morphisms between direct sums can be thought of as matrixes, hence you get here actually 4 copies of $\mathrm{Hom} (M,M)$, your proof only considers the "diagonal" maps. For example, if you have $M\oplus M'$, you get $$\mathrm{Hom} (M\oplus M',M\oplus M') \cong \mathrm{Hom}(M,M')  \oplus  \mathrm{Hom}(M,M)^{\oplus 2} \oplus  \mathrm{Hom}(M',M)   $$
Also $M\cong M\oplus M$ seems kind of strong, nealry as if your object is the zero object or you will get an Eilenberg swindle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S=\text{Hom}_R(M,M) \cong \text{Hom}_R(M, M \oplus M) \cong \text{Hom}_R(M,M) \oplus \text{Hom}_R(M,M)=S \oplus S.$

Comment: True, but not very elucidating. I think OP is interested in the isomorphism in the middle.

Comment: Well that one is just univ property of $\oplus$.

Comment: @Enkidu Right, it is useful to mention this.

Comment: Do you know of any places that I could learn about the universal property of $\oplus$, what exactly that means and why it explains the middle isomorphism?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom, Try to show this one $\text{Hom}_R(M, M \oplus M) \cong \text{Hom}_R(M,M) \oplus \text{Hom}_R(M,M)$.